how to calculate this integral using scipy/numpy?
i have the folowing question enter image description here
it's written badly, but for those values of alpha and beta (0.32, 12) i need to find the minimal k at which the integral from -inf to inf of that expression is less than pi.
but this code I tried didn't work as for the example I got the value of 4 and not 15 so I don't know how to continue.
this is what i got with some help of chatGPT, when the last print shows a positive value that means that i've met my condition and it happens at k=2.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def a(i):
    return (12 * i - 11) ** 0.32

def sinc(t):
    if t == 0:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return np.sin(t) / t

def p(x, k):
    product = 1.0
    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        product *= sinc(x / a(i))
    return product

def P(k):
    integral, _ = quad(lambda x: p(x, k), -np.inf, np.inf)
    return integral

for value in range(1,5):
    print(f"P({value}) =", P(value))
    print(f'pi - P({value}) =', np.pi - P(value))

### solution was 2


It doesn't solve the problem, but you have an even integrand, so you could integrate from 0 to infinity and then double the result.

@lastchance didn't think about it, but it still doesn't help to really compute this

Could you clarify your question (the linked image). At the top it says beta=12, alpha=32/100. Then, at the bottom, it says beta=2, alpha=1. Which parameters do you want?

@lastchance the first value are the real problem, the 1,2 values are for example, and it says that for those values the condition would first hold for k=15

The key point is k=8. It is beta*k-1, or 2k-1 that is 15. Everything before that is exactly equal to pi.

3blue1brown made a video about this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851U557j6HE

Already noted in the comments to one of the other answers, @Rob. But it’s a cracking video and helped to explain the paper.

Interestingly, most methods provided by scipy.integrate yields a number very close to pi but less than pi from k = 2 onwards. eg quad, fixed_quad, quadrature, romberg. Even using the diffferent gaus quadratures in scipy.special.root_* yields to a value less than pi by k=2.
import numpy as np
import scipy
    
def fn(x, k, alpha, beta):
  x = np.array(x).reshape(-1,1)
  w =  x / (beta * np.arange(1, k + 1) - (beta - 1)) ** alpha / np.pi
  return np.sinc(w).prod(1)

scipy.integrate.quad(fn, -np.inf, np.inf, (5, 1, 2))
(3.1415926520655124, 4.664127099015817e-08)

This value is already less than pi and k is only 5 so had to try other methods
In order to use the other methods,  a vectorized function that is scaled to [-1,1] interval has to be defined:
def fn2(t, k, alpha, beta):
  t =  np.array(t).reshape(-1)
  results = np.zeros_like(t)
  index = np.abs(t) != 1
  t_ = t[index]
  denom = 1 - t_**2
  x = (t_/denom).reshape(-1,1)
  w =  x / (beta * np.arange(1, k + 1) - (beta - 1)) ** alpha / np.pi
  results[index] =  np.sinc(w).prod(1)*(1 + t_ **2) / denom**2
  return results


scipy.integrate.quadrature(fn2, -1,1,(10,1,2), maxiter=300, vec_func = True)
(3.1415900583875214, 3.7533582020188305e-08)

scipy.integrate.romberg(fn2, -1,1,(7,1,2), divmax = 20, vec_func = True)
array([3.14159266])

Still no success in the integration since the value is less than pi for K=10
Lets try julia:
## %%julia
using Pkg
using QuadGK

function fn(x, k, alpha, beta)
  w = x ./(beta .* range(1, k) .- (beta - 1)).^alpha
  x == 0 ? 1. : prod(sin.(w)./w)
end
quadgk(x -> fn(x, 5, 1., 2.), -Inf, Inf)
(3.1415926432027703, 4.3290522541976784e-8)

Also no success. since value is less than pi for k = 5
Mathematica?
beta = 2;
alpha = 1;
For[k = 2, k<10, k++, 
    Print["k=", k, " ", Integrate[Product[Sinc[x/(beta*i - beta+1)^alpha],{i,1,k}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]<Pi]]

Results:
k=1 False
k=2 False
k=3 False
k=4 False
k=5 False
k=6 False
k=7 False
k=8 True
k=9 True

So, Mathematica says that at k=8 the result is already less than pi.
What about R?
## %%R
fn <- function(x, k, alpha, beta){
  a <- (beta * seq_len(k) - beta + 1)**alpha
  ifelse(x==0, 1, apply(sin(w <- outer(x, a, '/'))/w, 1, prod))
}
integrate(fn, -Inf, Inf, k=10, alpha=1,beta=2)
3.141601 with absolute error < 0.00012

This seems to be successful. Compute for K such that the integral is  less than pi.
##%%R
g <- function(k) {
  integrate(fn, -Inf, Inf, k=k, alpha=1,beta=2)$value - pi
}
uniroot(g, c(3,20))
$root
[1] 14.99996

$f.root
[1] 1.430762e-07

$iter
[1] 19

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05

R gives the root as 15. You can use minimize/optim and both methods returns 15.
Since R uses Gauss-kronrod  quadrature nodes and values, there should be a python implementation for that. but could not find any.
next try fixed_quad playing around with n. n = 200 seems to match the results from R:
scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(fn2, -1,1,(10,1,2), 200)
(3.141602220677316, None)

g = lambda k : scipy.integrate.fixed_quad(fn2, -1,1,(int(k),1,2), n = 200)[0] - np.pi
scipy.optimize.root_scalar(g, bracket=(4, 20))
      converged: True
           flag: converged
 function_calls: 53
     iterations: 52
           root: 15.000000000000028

Notice that the root = 15. Wow but that is trial and error with regards to the n, without which one cannot obtain the needed solution.
Other approximations?
nodes1, weights1 = scipy.special.roots_jacobi(1000,0,0)
fn2(nodes1,10,1,2)@weights1
3.1415923602907556
nodes2, weights2 = scipy.special.roots_legendre(1000)
fn2(nodes2,10,1,2)@weights2
3.1415923602907556

These values are still less than pi. So why Only R gives the results yet every other method fails?
Perhaps the author of that question used R. Every other approximation is close to pi, but mostly less than pi.
NB: I could not find the gauss-kronrod in python.
Conclusion: This is an ill-defined problem as the results of the integration need to be pi. thus an approximation could be smaller or larger than pi, and due to numerical approximations, different platforms would yield different results. eg the fixed_quad method used above will yield different results for different n. its not common to have a specific n that would yield the needed results. I had to optimize to find n=200.

Mathematica seems to show that with k=8 (alpha = 1, beta = 2) the integral is less than pi.

@jared you could edit to add the code and the results. It seems OP needs something that is by chance/luck. I am not quite sure as to why the paper/image shows 15 as the results yet only R and fixed_quad so far matches that. I believe the one who set the problem used R.

k=8 is correct. (Note that 2k-1 is then 15). But you will need symbolic maths, not a numerical integrator, to prove it.

@lastchance the true value for k=1:5 is pi.  check here After which it approximates. Thus the approximation will be platform and method dependent. Hence no true value for k. Notice that as k increases, the approximation deviates further from pi but to a number larger than pi eg try k = 50 or 100

Have a look at the paper cited in my answer. According to that, the integral is exactly pi for k=1 to 7 and then something different (but VERY close to pi) for k=8.

For the case beta=2, alpha=1 the correct answer is k=8. (Kudos to Jared for his comment in another thread).
The confusion over the number 15 is that 2k-1 = 15 in that instance.
This was proved by Borwein and Borwein, "Some remarkable Properties of Sinc and Related Integrals", The Ramanujan Journal, 5, 73-89, 2001. You can find it at https://www.carmamaths.org/resources/db90/pdfs/db90-119.00.pdf
Look at their equation 10 and the text around it. (Note that their integral runs from 0 to infinity, so is half the current one. To reiterate, it is k=8 and 2k-1=15 that is the interesting case).
For every k value below this Nate3384's integral (which runs from -infinity to infinity rather than 0 to infinity) would be exactly pi.
I include a screenshot from their paper. The paragraph after equation 10 is amusing (and salutary). I don't think any purely numerical method would have the accuracy to get this - you would need symbolic maths, such as Mathematica or, possibly, Sympy. So: over to the Sympy experts!
Screenshot from Borwein and Borwein's paper:


should it be larger than pi or less than pi? this shows larger than pi

I think it can go both ways - your example is for k=20 (2k-1=39). Whatever it is ... it's not equal  to pi. I'm still looking for an alternative method using complex variables and contour integration, but no luck so far.

I tried even for larger values ie 150 and stil gets a value greater than pi. not less than pi

It's the value for k=8 that matters. That is less than pi (at least according to the paper). What happens for higher values is not being asked.

thanks for this, i think the professor gave us this as a troll question, we're first-year EE class in Python, and we're still way off Fourier transforms and all of that, I'll give that paper a read later, but it seems like this problem is way more involved than the rest of the questions we were given

Thanks for the shoutout. And I thought this problem looked familiar... https://youtu.be/851U557j6HE?si=kVZtVzJYvA7GyMcd

That’s awesome! It’s a good thing the OP didn’t ask for the sequence with the 2.cos(x) in front, though! That really would have caught me out.
